# How to prove that a matrix A, size nxn, with n linearly independent eigenvectors is similar to a diagonal matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

EDIT:

In one direction, assuming that $A$ has $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors, then I can compute the action of $A$ on the n eigenvectors, and expand each image as a linear combination of the n eigenvectors:

$$Av_1 = \lambda_1v_1 = \lambda_1v_1 + 0v_2 + ... +0v_n$$
$$Av_2 = \lambda_2v_2 = 0v_1 + \lambda_2 v_2 + ... +0v_n$$

...

$$Av_n = \lambda_nv_n = 0v_1 + 0v_2 + ... +\lambda_n v_n$$

And now taking the transpose of the coefficients gives the matrix of the linear operator, with respect to the basis of eigenvectors, which is diagonal.

Is my proof in this direction ok?  It is purely...computational, so I hope it suffices, and that I don't need something a little more algebraic?

Problem statement:

I want to prove that an $nxn$ matrix $A$ has $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors if and only if it is similar to a diagonal matrix.

I'm not sure how to get started on a proof - of course, the concrete computations is no problem at all.

Any hints and suggestions are welcome.

Thanks,

Comment: construct a matrix $P$ whose columns are these eigen vectors. Now think about $PAP^{-1}$.

Comment: Any guesses on what the diagonal matrix might be? You can make an educated guess based on the context of the problem

Comment: In basis of eigenvectors, the matrix will be diagonal by definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fairly standard stuff.

If $A v_k = \lambda_k v_k$ then let
$V = \begin{bmatrix} v_1 & \cdots & v_n\end{bmatrix}$ and
$\Lambda = \operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1, \cdots , \lambda_n )$. Note that
$V$ is invertible. Then the above equations can be written as
$AV = V \Lambda$ which gives $V^{-1} A V = \Lambda$.

If $A$ is similar to a diagonal matrix $\Lambda\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1, \cdots , \lambda_n )$, then there is some $V$
such that $V^{-1}A V = \Lambda$. Hence $A V = V \Lambda$. Let $e_k$ be the
$k$th unit vector, and let $\lambda_k$ be the $k$th diagonal entry of $\Lambda$ then
$AV e_k = V \Lambda e_k = \lambda_k V e_k$. If we let $v_k = V e_k$ then
we have $A v_k = \lambda v_k$. Since $V$ is invertible, it follows that the
$v_k$ are linearly independent.

Comment: Hi @copper.hat -- thanks for your quick response and answer.  I have not read the second part of  your answer but I will take a peak at it soon, if I do not come up with something.  However, is my proof (just edited my question) in one direction ok?  It is basically what you wrote up, but yours is purely algebraic.  Is mine...incomplete?  Thanks,

Comment: I don't follow your statement 'And now taking the transpose...'. Once you have $Av_k = \lambda_k v_k$ you are essentially finished, since in the basis $v_1,...,v_n$ the matrix corresponding to $A$ is just the diagonal with entries $\lambda_k$. I just wanted to given an explicit $V$ above.

Comment: Hi @copper.hat, taking the transpose would just be the standard algorithm in computing the matrix representation of A w.r.t. some basis, so I basically just said that for completeness.  I have a follow-up question if you don't mind:  I realize I have not shown the similarity like you did.  So, following what you did, I am almost there, except for this one tricky part:  If S is my matrix with the columns as eignenvectors, D the diagonal matrix of eigenvalues, then the computation SD gives a matrix with columns [$\lambda_1v_1, ... , \lambda_nv_n$] =  [$Av_1, ... , Av_n$].

Comment: now... is this equal to AS?  It of course has to be, so that I have SD = AS, and then $D=S^{-1}AS$ and we are finished in this direction.  But how do I get that last matrix decomposition, AS?  Can I view it as "factoring out A" from the matrix S?  Like block matrix ideas, treating A as a scalar...is this a valid way of thinking about it?  Thanks @copper.hat,

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 'But how do I get that last...'. Since you have $D=S^{-1}AS$, you know that $A$ is similar to $D$, a diagonal matrix.

Comment: Hi @copper.hat, I mean how do we know that the matrix $[Av_1, ... , Av_n]$ = $[A] * [S]$?  neither is assumed to be diagonal or of any other particularly nice form, so it's not obvious just by inspection -- how do we deal with the computations?  Thanks,

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. This is just ordinary matrix multiplication. Since $S=\begin{bmatrix} v_1 & \cdots & v_n \end{bmatrix}$ we have $AS = \begin{bmatrix} A v_1 & \cdots & A v_n \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Right...I think I just don't know that part.  Although I think it shows up early in the book by Trefethen and Bau, which I have skimmed through in the past.  So $SA$ is $\large [S\vec a_1 ... S\vec a_n]$, right?  In particular, it is *not* equal to $[Av_1 ... Av_n]$ since matrix multiplication is not (in general) commutative.  Is this correct?  Thanks for your time @copper.hat

Comment: Well, in general two matrices don't commute. The result follows just by computation, there's no magic.

Comment: Ok got it - thanks again @copper.hat :-)